# Comparing date from pandas dataframe to current date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to write a script that does a specific action on a certain day. So for example, if today is the 6/30/2019 and in my dataframe there is a 6/30/2019 entry, xyz proceeds to happen. However, I am having troubles comparing the date from a dataframe to a DateTime date. Here's how I created the dataframe

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

Test1 = pd.read_excel(r"some path")
```

Heres what the output looks like when I print the dataframe.

```
  symbol  ...                  phase
0   MDCO  ...                Phase 2
1   FTSV  ...              Phase 1/2
2    NVO  ...                Phase 2
3    PFE  ...  PDUFA priority review
4   ATRA  ...                Phase 1
```

Heres' how the 'event_date' column prints out

```
0    05/18/2019
1    06/30/2019
2    06/30/2019
3    06/11/2019
4    06/29/2019
```

So I've tried a few things I've seen in other threads.
I've tried:

```
if (Test1['event_date'] == now):
    print('True')
```

That returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've tried reformatting my the data with:

```
column_A = datetime.strptime(Test1['event_date'], '%m %d %y').date()
```

which returns this

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

I've tried this

```
   if any(Test1.loc(Test1['event_date'])) == now:
```

and that returned this

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I don't know why python is telling me the str is a dataframe, I'm assuming it has something to do with how python exports data from an excel sheet. I'm not sure how to fix this.

I simply want python to check if any of the rows have the same `"event_date"` value as the current date and return the index or return a boolean to be used in a loop.

Comment: Try: `df['Your Date column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Your Date Column']` and then `str` datetime date to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

da = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
# converting the column to datetime, you can check the dtype of the column by doing
# df['event_date'].dtypes
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])    

# generate a df with rows where there is a match
df_co = df.loc[df['event_date'] == da]
```

I would suggest doing xy or what is required in a column based on the match in the same column. i.e.

`df.loc[df['event_date'] == da,'column name'] = df['x'] + df['y']`

Easier than looping.

Comment: Why is it easier than looping?

Comment: a for loop will go and check the condition again and again. But here you are basically selecting the rows and giving the formula for the column/value which I assume is to be generated for rows which match the criteria. Loop will take a lot of time compared to assigning values.

Comment: If I plan on running it indefinitely, would that not create a mess of columns?

Comment: running indefinitely? I think it might be better to post up a new question because I can''t understand the use case.

Comment: I guess to better clarify I want to run the code once a day. That was my first sentence of the post. Edit: Indefinitely was just an extreme case as I don't know when I will stop my experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import time 

# keep only y,m,d, and throw out the rest:
now =  (time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))

# the column in the dataframe needs to be converted to datetime first.
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])

# to return indices
df[df['event_date']==now].index.values

# if you want to loop, you can do:
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['event_date'] == now:
        print(ix)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help as well. I ended up using the itterrows to get the job done.