# Filtering all entries on today's date (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to filter out all the rows in my data that have today's date in a column.

The (Fixture,Date) column has pandas datetime type of values.

```
0     2021-05-02
1     2021-06-02
2     2021-06-02
3     2021-06-02
4     2021-06-02    
189   2021-06-02
190   2021-06-02
191   2021-07-02
192   2021-07-02
193   2021-08-02
```

I had the following code filtering it in my script and if I can remember correctly it was working in the past.

```
today= probs_final[probs_final["Fixture","Date"].dt.date.eq(datetime.datetime.today().date())]
```

But now it returns an empty data-frame.

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093654/847773) , but this does not work either:

```
today= probs_final[probs_final["Fixture","Date"].dt.date.eq(str(datetime.datetime.now().date()))]
```

Comment: Well... None of these dates match today's date... ?

Comment: They do the last one. OK, so 2021-08-02 is suposed to be today. str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) returns 2021-02-08.

Comment: My original .csv file keeps the dateformat like this 08/02/2021

Comment: 2021-08-02 is not today in ISO date format, which your pandas is used here. 2021-08-02 is equivalent to american 08/02/2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you misunderstand the date format. 2021-08-02 means August 2nd, 2021 not February 8th, 2021 (which may now be today in some time zones).

Your code is fine, your dates aren't.

Edit:

To answer the source problem, which seems to be your ingestion of a CSV file. I have had some success using the infer_datetime_format parameter of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv).

```
pd.read_csv(..., infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: Thanks I also figured out why it stopped working suddenly, because in the past I had dates like 25th of January (25/01/2021) and the could be infered automatically with 08/02/2021 it could go either way.